# Programming pipes in c. Trying to execute piped commands cd and pwd, but it does not work out for me

Tags: c, linux

So I am programming pipes in C (to support multiple pipes). Currently I am testing it with hardcoded commands. I tried to execute cd command to change current working directory and pwd command to display new directory. But it does not work for me: cd does not change working directory and pwd display old directory of my Debug folder in project root. I will be very thankful if you clarify the cause of this problem to me. Thank you!

Here is the code

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {    
    char *cd[] = {"cd", "/Users/user01/Desktop", NULL};
    char *pwd[] = {"pwd", NULL};

    char **cmd [] = {cd, pwd, NULL};

    loop_pipe(cmd);
    return 0;
}

void loop_pipe(char ***cmd){

    int   p[2];
    pid_t pid;
    int   fd_in = 0;

    while (*cmd != NULL)
    {
        pipe(p);
        if ((pid = fork()) == -1){
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else if (pid == 0){
            dup2(fd_in, 0); //change the input according to the old one
            if (*(cmd + 1) != NULL)
                dup2(p[1], 1);
            close(p[0]);
            execvp((*cmd)[0], *cmd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }else{
            wait(NULL);
            close(p[1]);
            fd_in = p[0]; //save the input for the next command
            cmd++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cd` is not a program. In the shell, it is implemented as a built-in.

Think about what would happen if that were not the case: The new child process would change directory and then promptly exit, effecting no persistent change. Parent and child processes do not share working directories.

I doubt your goal actually is to change directories *per se*, but if that were what you wanted, you would have to do it "manually" in your parent process, using a `chdir()` call.